# TikZ: Sample document with several fonts having different usage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, tug

Is there an example of use of TikZ with very different fonts, like the ones available at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/?

There seems to be very different type of fonts.
I succeded in using "calligra" for example, but other ones seem to have a different structure, and I think there must be a simple way to use several of them in one document.
For example, these seem to have very different usage (Cf. the "Usage" paragraphs):

- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/cyklop/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/dejavusans/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/qtarabian/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/artificialuncial/

How can I have a text with all of them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (5,5) {\Huge \calligra Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you're looking for, but if you are able & willing to use `LuaLaTeX` (or `XeLaTeX`, for that matter) you can use any regular .ttf or .otf font.

Comment: I am using LuaLaTeX. I succeeded (not easily) in using together 8 fonts mentioned on tug.org. See my answer in the same post, with some other fonts that I don't know how to use.
I still have a superficial understanding of LaTeX, so the different ways different fonts are used is still cryptic for me. I love the following pdf document, but I don't have its source: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc. I'd like to have/make something similar.

Comment: You should probably first make yourself familiar with how to use fonts with LaTeX in general. There are large differences between the traditional, package-based approach that is confined to fonts for which a packages exists (and which you probably refer to), and a newer open approach that allows you to use any font that is installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded in creating the kind of sample document I had in mind. Here it is.

I don't really understand what I'm doing for now (for example : The T1, the B1, the differences between the fonts...), but that will come later, little by little.
Any suggestion of improvement is welcome :-)

By the way, I found a pdf with what I expected (and much more), but the latex-source was not given: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fontspec-all-the-fonts/hjrpnxhrrtxc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cyklop}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
\usepackage{auncial}
\usepackage[B1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] at (5,15) {\Huge {\fontspec{cyklop} Sample text in cyklop}};
\node[draw] at (5,13) {\Huge {\fontspec{DejaVuSans} Sample text in DejaVuSans}};
\node[draw] at (5,11) {\Huge {\fontspec{QTArabian} Sample text in QTArabian}};
\node[draw] at (5,9) {\Huge \aunclfamily Sample text in aunclfamily};
\node[draw] at (5,7) {\Huge \calligra Sample text in calligra};
\node[draw] at (5,5) {\Huge {\fontspec{QTBoulevard} Sample text in QTBoulevard}};
\node[draw] at (5,3) {\Huge \bbfamily Sample text in bbold / bbfamily};
\node[draw] at (5,1) {\Huge \bsifamily Sample text in pbsi / bsifamily};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT :
There are still many fonts that I don't know how to use together.
For example:

- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/carlito/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernteletypequotation/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansmathfonts/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/europeancomputermodernsansserifquotation/
- https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernsansserifoutline/